# Remove html tags in subreport

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have a subreport in SSRS which returns a text embedded in HTML tags. I will like to know if there is a way of stripping these HTML tags so as to only have the text. I am using VS 2008.

I have tried using a regex function as below to strip the HTML tags but this does not work:

```
Shared  FUNCTION RemoveHtml(ByVal Text As String) AS String
        IF Text IsNot Nothing Then 
        Dim mRemoveTagRegex AS NEW System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(“<(.|\n)+?>”) 

        Return mRemoveTagRegex.Replace(text, "")
        End If 
end function
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably just use a combination of the built-in functions provided with SSRS to do what you need.  I'd recommend combining `Mid` with `InStr`. The following expression will take the value between the last character of the opening HTML tag and the first character of the closing HTML tag.

```
=MID(Fields!Field.Value, 
     InStr(Fields!Field.Value, ">") + 1, 
     InStrRev(Fields!Field.Value, "</")
     -Len(Left(Fields!Field.Value, 
          InStr(Fields!Field.Value, ">") + 1)))
```

Edit: It got a little more complex than I thought, but this should do the trick.